New fields in the users table generated by amnah in yii2
I'm building an application using yii2 and amnah to manage users, I would like to know if I can add new fields to the users table that amnah creates in the database, such as a field to store photos or some other information
is it possible to do that?

Is it possible? Yes, it is.
Yii2's models based on yii\db\ActiveRecord gets their list of attributes
directly from their DB tables. So adding a new field is as simple as adding a new column to the DB table. You can do that by creating a migration and adding new column in it.
This is enough if you don't need to add attribute labels or validation rules for new fields. If you want to add that, you will also need to extend existing model and configure amnah's module and user component to use your extended model instead of its own.
To extend existing model:
<?php

namespace app\models;

use amnah\yii2\user\models\User as BaseUser;

class User extends BaseUser
{
    public function rules(): array
    {
        $rules = parent::rules();
        // This is just an example, set up validation rules as you need them
        $rules[] = ['my_new_field', 'required'];
        $rules[] = ['my_new_field', 'string', 'min' => 3];
        return $rules;
    }

    public function attributeLabels(): array
    {
        $labels = parent::attributeLabels();
        // This is just an example, set up labels as you need them
        $labels['my_new_field'] = 'My fancy new field';
        return $labels;
    }
}

Edit your config files to change module's configuration:
'components' => [
    'user' => [
        'class' => 'amnah\yii2\user\components\User',
        // set up component to use our extended model as identity class
        'identityClass' => 'app\models\User',
    ],
],
'modules' => [
    'user' => [
        'class' => 'amnah\yii2\user\Module',
        'modelClasses'  => [
            // set up amnah's user module to use our extended model class
            'User' => 'app\models\User',
        ],
    ],
],

Should it be done? No, it shouldn't.
The DB tables were created by 3rd party package so they should be left to be managed by that package. There is chance that some future update of that package will change the structure of its DB tables. If you modify the structure of those tables you are creating possibility that there will be some conflicts between your changes and changes introduced in future package's updates.
Instead you can create your own db table with 1:1 relation to table from amnah's package and store your own data there. If needed, you can extend model (as shown above) to add the relation definition to user model.
